# How to Use D3 elements inside SAPUI5 , when using JS views?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sapui5

Suppose we want to use D3 JS library data visualization ability and use it inside SAPUI5 application , (*already using VIZ library which is based on D3 in sap.m but want to have more elements and more capabilities to represent data* )

- Is it possible and advisable ?
- If yes ,then are there any other framework based on D3 library which can be utilized to do the integration as SAPUI5 is a object oriented framework and writing D3 code inside the view is not working ?

Find below the failed trial of integration , where execution of standalone D3 code was successful.

The error it is shown in console is :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Code:

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    
    var canvas = d3.select("idPage01")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width",4000)
     .attr("height",2000)
     .attr("length",100);

         canvas.append("circle")
         .attr("cx", 200)
         .attr("cy",200)
         .attr("r",10);


    var lv_Page = new sap.m.Page("idPage01",{
        title: "VIZ",
        content: [
            canvas

                ]
    });     
    
    return lv_Page;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible and advisable ?

Absolutely yes.

> If yes ,then are there any other framework based on D3 library which can be utilized to do the integration as SAP UI5 is a object oriented framework and writing D3 code inside the view is not working ?

You don't need to include other framework to do this, it should be possible to directly write d3 code in js view, but that's not a good practice. You should write a separate chart module and consume it in your view.

**user3808826**'s answer is great, but I think creating a custom control to integrate a chart into UI5 application is overkill, I've written a blog about another approach, which I think is easier and superior. Check it out.

https://hatelove85911.github.io/2016/03/23/Integrate-D3-chart-into-UI5-Application/

Although in my blog, I'm using the xml view, it should be very easy to convert into js view.

Comment: I am using the code you mention in your blog. I can successfully draw the pie chart but only for a sec then it disappear.